# snap-store or basically any snap app cannot be run: user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, apt, upgrade, software-updates, snap

I was running several apps that were installed with Snap Store. I was not using the system for some time and blindly run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo snap refresh
```

after reboot bdzionk. When I start any of these apps or even snap-store itself it just silently finishes. Everything else works as expected.

To better diagnose the problem I tried to start the apps with command line:

```
pdebski@system:~$ ps -ea | grep snap
    764 ?        00:00:01 snapd
pdebski@system:~$ snap list
Name                     Version                     Rev   Tracking       Publisher   Notes
chromium                 83.0.4103.61                1165  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
core                     16-2.45                     9289  latest/stable  canonical✓  core
core18                   20200427                    1754  latest/stable  canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804          3.28.0-17-gde3d74c.de3d74c  128   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes        0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
kde-frameworks-5-core18  5.61.0                      32    latest/stable  kde✓        -
midori                   v8.0-31-gf6b3b1e            550   latest/stable  kalikiana   -
snap-store               3.31.1+git187.84b64e0b      415   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snapd                    2.45                        7777  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
pdebski@system:~$ snap run snap-store
/snap/snap-store/415/bin/desktop-launch: line 51: /home/pdebski/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
18:13:30:0737 GLib-GIO g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
18:13:30:0740 Gtk Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
18:13:30:0746 Gtk cannot open display: :1
pdebski@system:~$ ls -l .co*/u*s
-rw------- 1 pdebski pdebski 632 mar 21  2018 .config/user-dirs.dirs
```

I do not want `user-dirs.dirs` or any other file in my home directory world-readable, nevertheless I changed the permissions to check what happens:

```
pdebski@system:~/.config$ chmod go+r u*s
pdebski@system:~/.config$ ls -ld .
drwxr-xr-x 27 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze  5 19:52 .
pdebski@system:~/.config$ ls -al u*
-rw-r--r--  1 pdebski pdebski  632 mar 21  2018 user-dirs.dirs
pdebski@system:~/.config$ ls -ald ../.c*g
drwxr-xr-x 27 pdebski pdebski 4096 cze  5 19:52 ../.config
pdebski@system:~/.config$ snap-store
/snap/snap-store/415/bin/desktop-launch: line 51: /home/pdebski/.config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied
20:45:44:0906 GLib-GIO g_app_info_get_name: assertion 'G_IS_APP_INFO (appinfo)' failed
20:45:44:0951 Gtk Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
20:45:45:0012 Gtk cannot open display: :1
```

I am stuck. What's wrong?

Comment: How are you installing your `snap` packages?  In my experience, `snap` packages are installed for all users and require `root` privileges user to install them (i.e. `sudo snap install hello-world`).  Researching this issue, I did find that `snap` allows a user to login to a store with `snap login`, and then they are allowed to install user level `snap`s, so maybe that is what `snap-store` is doing.

Comment: Some time ago Snap Store was running as expected and and the apps were running as well. I was not using the system for some time and blindly run ```apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade ; snap refresh``` after reboot all runs except snap-installed apps.

Comment: Are the posted commands/output from a session belonging to `pdebski` or some other user?  From what you have provided, I would expect things to work when logged in as `pdebski`, but as you noted it will likely not work with other users unless you allow them to read the contents of your `$HOME` directory.

Comment: Yes, I run the commands as pdebski (me)

Comment: Ah, then did the permissions of the `/home/pdebski/.config/user-dirs.dirs` directory (or parent directory) get set to owned by `root` or some other user, preventing `pdebski` from reading them?

Comment: Cannot check it now, but @GracefullRestart you're genius! Respectful regards...

Comment: Hmm, @GracefulRestart apparently it is not that permissions issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have manjaro but had this issue already several times, a quick snap store reinstall solved this (try following their instructions https://snapcraft.io/snap-store)

and now I have rectangles instead text characters, which I can solve via:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
sudo rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @borabora indeed reinstalling snap-store helps:

```
$ snap help
The snap command lets you install, configure, refresh and remove snaps.
Snaps are packages that work across many different Linux distributions,
enabling secure delivery and operation of the latest apps and utilities.

Usage: snap <command> [<options>...]

Commands can be classified as follows:

         Basics: find, info, install, list, remove
        ...more: refresh, revert, switch, disable, enable
        History: changes, tasks, abort, watch
        Daemons: services, start, stop, restart, logs
       Commands: alias, aliases, unalias, prefer
  Configuration: get, set, unset, wait
        Account: login, logout, whoami
    Permissions: connections, interface, connect, disconnect
      Snapshots: saved, save, check-snapshot, restore, forget
          Other: version, warnings, okay, ack, known, model, create-cohort
    Development: run, pack, try, download, prepare-image

For more information about a command, run 'snap help <command>'.
For a short summary of all commands, run 'snap help --all'.
$ snap refresh snap-store
snap "snap-store" has no updates available
$ snap remove snap-store
snap-store removed
$ snap install snap-store
snap-store 3.31.1+git187.84b64e0b from Canonical✓ installed
$ snap-store
21:58:29:0941 Gtk Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
21:58:30:0253 GsPluginOdrs failed to get distro name: Failed to open file “/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/etc/os-release”: Permission denied
21:58:30:0287 Gs  enabled plugins: odrs, rewrite-resource, snap, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
21:58:30:0288 Gs  disabled plugins: appstream, desktop-categories, desktop-menu-path, dpkg, dummy, epiphany, fedora-pkgdb-collections, generic-updates, hardcoded-blacklist, hardcoded-featured, hardcoded-popular, modalias, os-release, provenance, provenance-license, repos, shell-extensions
21:58:34:0513 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
21:58:34:0516 Gs  updates-shell: failed to get updates: no plugin could handle get-updates
21:58:34:0516 Gs  failed to create an app for */*/*/*/system/*
21:58:34:0516 Gs  failed to get system app
21:58:34:0541 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
21:58:34:0552 Gs  Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
21:58:34:0565 Gs  hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
21:58:34:0777 Gs  hiding category audio-video featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
21:58:35:0147 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
21:58:35:0350 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
21:58:35:0767 GsPluginSnap Failed to load snap icon: local snap has no icon
```

(snap-store window appears)

Notice different error messages - apparently snap-store quality requires more refining.

Probably during the system update kernel or some libs were updated which broke compatibility. It was not necessary to reinstall other Snap apps. Reinstalling just the store fixed prereqs automatically for all other apps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error recently coming up and indeed removing and installing the snap fixed the problem. I looked at the permissions (from `snap-store` after the reinstallation) of a particular snap before and after and it seems that somehow all the permissions have been reset so it's clear why this is failing.

Before the removal and (re)installation all those permissions were disabled:
[image: permissions for discord as an example]

I don't know of a better way than to reinstall each affected snap.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the snap-store didnt help me. It wasnt installed to begin with. I ended up reinstalling snapd with apt (remove and install) and then also reinstalling each snap because they showed broken in `snap list` (snap remove install).

Answer (score 0):

Reconfiguring snapd worked for me:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure snapd`

Answer (score -1):

```
snap list
```

proceed by removing and reinstalling all broken app

```
sudo snap remove core20
```

```
sudo snap install core20
```